# Symfony 2 - How to define service parameters in parameters.yml.dist

Tags: symfony

Let's say we have a **service/bundle that need a parameter to be set** in **parameters.yml**. That dependency should be reflected in parameters.yml.dist.

But **how do you define that dependency** in your service/bundle so it is *automagically* added to parameters.yml.dist (ideally with a preset default value) when someone adds that service/bundle to his project?

What is the *correct* way to do it?

**Disclaimer:** I know this is (or *should* be) a really basic question but I've been looking for the answer for a while and I can't find it, so it's possible that others can't find it either.

Comment: Why do you have a service/bundle that need a parameter to be set in parameters.yml? Can't you define it inside the bundle ?

Comment: If it's in parameters.yml is more straightforward for the final user to configure that going through every parameter file in every bundle/service, isn't it? Isn't that the point of parameters.yml, to have a centralized configuration file for parameters that tend to change for every instance of the program?

Comment: Totally not, use bundle configuration for the final user to easily configure your bundle.

Comment: The point of parameters.yml is to have server specific parameters or ones that you don't want to include in your SCM repositories. Users can chose to store all of their parameters in that and reference them in their `app/config/config(_dev|_test).yml` but it isn't necessary, or even a regular way to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you can check it:

In your composer.json file in custom bundle add config:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "src/MyBundle/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

Then make `parameters.yml.dist` file in your `config` dir.

Comment: Nice try but he wants to update the app/config/paramters files which simply is not going to happen.

Comment: Only scripts defined in root `composer.json` of project can be executed.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I did'nt know that before, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing today. While I couldn't find a way to 'push it up' to `parameters.yml.dist` but I could set a default value for it from within the bundle's `build` method:

```
/**
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 */
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    //Make sure we have the parameter defined by default
    if (!$container->hasParameter('my.little.pony')) {
        $container->setParameter('my.little.pony', []);
    }
}
```

It might be sufficient in some cases, where a default value will do.
So if you inject the parameter as an argument to a service it won't die.

Answer (score -1):

First You need to configure Your bundle to read from `config.yml` - please read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html).

Then You can easily define Your bundle parameters in `parameters.yml` i.e.:

```
# app/config/config.yml

acme_social:
    twitter:
        client_id: %client_id%
        client_secret: %client_secret%
```

I know this is not a direct answer to Your question, but this is the proper way to achieve what You want.

Comment: Not a big fan of down voting newbies but this is wrong on many levels.

Comment: OP already knows it. He needs a way that will process `app/config/parameter.yml.dist` file of the end user (developer) that will use his bundle.

Comment: I recommend You to consider redesigning Your application - store needed parameters in database, wrapped in some entity, instead of editing file.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do it: writing documentation for the end user that will explain which parameters they can set and what are they mean.

Automatically process `parameters.yml.dist` after developer installs your bundle is impossible without your documentation. Because all scripts that can be executed by Composer must be defined in root `composer.json`. But you will need documentation that will explain developer how to set it up.